# My training of my model for imgae classification on colabs always stops without an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

When I setup my colab environment for training an image classifier model, it starts the training process and eventually stops on its own. I suspect the 12G of ram allocated isn't enough, because the bar on the ram turns orange and the process stops, the process then shows ctrl C (which is meant to stop training. Can I increase the RAM memory?

```
WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/slim/nets/inception_resnet_v2.py:373: The name tf.GraphKeys is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/slim/nets/mobilenet/mobilenet.py:397: The name tf.nn.avg_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.avg_pool2d instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From train.py:55: The name tf.logging.set_verbosity is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From train.py:55: The name tf.logging.INFO is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.logging.INFO instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From train.py:184: The name tf.app.run is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.app.run instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py:250: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
W1001 13:13:15.483837 139753866016640 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py:250: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
WARNING:tensorflow:From train.py:90: The name tf.gfile.MakeDirs is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.makedirs instead.

W1001 13:13:15.484074 139753866016640 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From train.py:90: The name tf.gfile.MakeDirs is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.makedirs instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py:102: The name tf.gfile.GFile is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.GFile instead.

W1001 13:13:15.484555 139753866016640 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py:102: The name tf.gfile.GFile is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.GFile instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From train.py:95: The name tf.gfile.Copy is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.copy instead.

W1001 13:13:15.490095 139753866016640 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From train.py:95: The name tf.gfile.Copy is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.copy instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py:266: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
W1001 13:13:15.501523 139753866016640 deprecation.py:323] From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py:266: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py:182: The name tf.FixedLenFeature is deprecated. Please use tf.io.FixedLenFeature instead.

W1001 13:13:15.505989 139753866016640 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py:182: The name tf.FixedLenFeature is deprecated. Please use tf.io.FixedLenFeature instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py:197: The name tf.VarLenFeature is deprecated. Please use tf.io.VarLenFeature instead.

W1001 13:13:15.506183 139753866016640 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py:197: The name tf.VarLenFeature is deprecated. Please use tf.io.VarLenFeature instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:64: The name tf.gfile.Glob is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.glob instead.

W1001 13:13:15.524426 139753866016640 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:64: The name tf.gfile.Glob is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.glob instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:71: The name tf.logging.warning is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.logging.warning instead.

W1001 13:13:15.527117 139753866016640 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:71: The name tf.logging.warning is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.logging.warning instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W1001 13:13:15.527241 139753866016640 dataset_builder.py:72] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:86: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(...)`.
W1001 13:13:15.533276 139753866016640 deprecation.py:323] From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:86: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(...)`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/interleave_ops.py:77: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_determinstic`.
W1001 13:13:15.533428 139753866016640 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/interleave_ops.py:77: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_determinstic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:155: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W1001 13:13:15.562883 139753866016640 deprecation.py:323] From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:155: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/drive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:43: DatasetV1.make_initializable_iterator (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py:1066: get_checkpoint_mtimes (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file utilities to get mtimes.
W1001 13:13:33.349572 139753866016640 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py:1066: get_checkpoint_mtimes (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file utilities to get mtimes.
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
I1001 13:13:33.351701 139753866016640 session_manager.py:500] Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
I1001 13:13:33.607376 139753866016640 session_manager.py:502] Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
I1001 13:13:38.220966 139753866016640 learning.py:754] Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt
I1001 13:13:38.410431 139752680122112 supervisor.py:1117] Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
I1001 13:13:38.413790 139753866016640 learning.py:768] Starting Queues.
2019-10-01 13:13:49.720631: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:111] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 1382 of 2048
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
I1001 13:13:49.738999 139752671729408 supervisor.py:1099] global_step/sec: 0
2019-10-01 13:13:54.929910: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:162] Shuffle buffer filled.
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 0.
I1001 13:13:56.814973 139752663336704 supervisor.py:1050] Recording summary at step 0.
INFO:tensorflow:global step 1: loss = 13.7762 (20.265 sec/step)
I1001 13:14:00.905406 139753866016640 learning.py:507] global step 1: loss = 13.7762 (20.265 sec/step)
^C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is turning Yellow and then it can also go to Red color, it means the RAM is getting filled up. YOu can not increase the RAM. It is fixed by Google.

One way to get over this is to decrease the size and if that doesn't work then also lower the number of neurons (number of parameters) in your model layers.

Comment: Please, im new to ML, how do i lower the number of neurons or decrese size

Comment: Sorry for asking, but is it the config file for my model?

Comment: I can not say exactly, it depends on the naming scheme. Where are you using the code from? Can you share the link?

Comment: And which exact model are you using from here?

Comment: ssd mobilenet v1

Comment: ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config